# Simplifying specific faces

Tags: mesh, topology

On the picture bellow there's a model i've been working on. At first, the mesh was pretty clean and optimized, with just enough vertices as it needed, but that was before i used the Subdivision Modifier. The mesh itself looks good after the modifier was applied, but in edit mode, the topology got pretty cluttered and hard to work with. The pill shaped cutout you see on the picture is something i want to extrude and then bevel, but the topology screws it up and i end up getting a deformed mesh. Here's the picture:
[image]

What i want, is to "simplify" those strange shapes and make them like the rest of the topology; quads with no triangles or god forbid N-gons.
Using dissolve makes n-gons and manually fixing the topology is going to be longer than the project itself.

Comment: it's not clear what your object is and is supposed to be, and anyway I guess it will probably be easier to re-do it from scratch... maybe describe what you want or give pictures and someone will tell what's the best way to do it

Comment: This specific shape is an IS-3's turret.
here's a picture: https://glossary-eu-static.gcdn.co/icons/wotb/5.1.0.4/uploaded/vehicles/hd/IS-3.png

Comment: I don't think you should 'Apply' the subdivision surface modifier because after applying the modifier, you cannot make any significant changes in the model later if you want to. I would suggest that you don't apply the modifier. This would not affect your final render. Also, after applying the modifier, your render times will increase drastically as compared to not applying the modifier.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to cut holes in a quarter sphere (well, kind of). Maybe beginning with a UV Sphere (i.e. concentric circles) is not the best way. Here is a try, beginning with a cube:

[image]

Comment: The topology was still going to be the same, since those weird flower-like shapes were caused AFTER the subdivision surface and i cut out the hole using Knife Project afterwards. I started over with a different method of manually extruding and scaling down a circle and applied the Subdivision modifier and it looks a lot better and the topology is clean. However, you've also fixed a problem with your method, because cutting out shapes with Knife Project can prove to be messy and your method seems a lot cleaner for my goal, so, thanks anyway!

Also, Ashutosh Budhdeo that's probably a good idea